# tmux: backspace and ctrl-backspace send both ^?

Tags: keyboard, tmux, control-characters

With FreeBSD 11.1 and tmux 2.7, pressing <kbd>←</kbd> (backspace) sends `^?` and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> does also send `^?`.

The default behavior (no tmux) is:

- `^H` for <kbd>←</kbd>
- `^?` for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

How can I get this default behavior with tmux? Or at least achieve that <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> don't send the *same* control character?

PS: okay, calling `stty ek` before starting tmux works. But isn't there some way to cleanly configure tmux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tmux only pays attention to the stty settings (no config- or terminfo-data).  Here's the code:

```
/*
 * Check for backspace key using termios VERASE - the terminfo
 * kbs entry is extremely unreliable, so cannot be safely
 * used. termios should have a better idea.
 */
bspace = tty->tio.c_cc[VERASE];
if (bspace != _POSIX_VDISABLE && (key & KEYC_MASK_KEY) == bspace)
    key = (key & KEYC_MASK_MOD) | KEYC_BSPACE;
```

So... setting `stty` is the only way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use Ctrl-Backspace (`^?`) as my Tmux prefix key. To get this to work, I had to stop the character being used as the *erase* character (`stty erase ""`) before starting Tmux.